# Android 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: android, spring

I m actually facing a problem while using Spring Framework for android.

When my user is connected, I need to get a list of task that he has to do during the day.
I ask my webservice (working great with wifi) but when I need to use it with 3G/Edge network it doesnt work and give me a :

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 504 Gateway Timeout
```

The connection with wifi takes ~3 seconds, and after 20-30 seconds in 3g/e and it crashed...

Any idea ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

There could be something wrong with your server environment, try to write some unittests and see how it behaves when mocking some timeouts; It may not even have anything to do with your android code.
Still - supposing that your server is fine, what api do you use in android for server connection? Usually it is preferred that you go with this [one](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) as it can gracefully handle timeouts.

Comment: It works with wifi call and HTTP call from a webpage . I m using the Spring Framework for Android to access data on the network.

Comment: It does work over wi-fi because over wi-fi your http request gets to the server in time, before the timeout is issued. Can you check on your server what timeouts are set for your requests?

Comment: The express default one : I dont know :/ . Btw I m using express and nodejs to make my WebServices work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm quite limited in knowledge when it comes to node.js, but as a generic approach I would try to determine how my server behaves in slow network conditions. Have a look at this link: http://krzychukula.blogspot.no/2012/09/how-to-simulate-slow-connection.html